# Custom user model (for custom fields, etc) with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, custom-attributes

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 2 application and used the default project skeleton with forms authentication. I have two requirements, the first is that it has to work on a Mono environment (ex. to run it within Apache) and the second is that I need a custom user model or at least, append additional information to the user information so I can access such data during runtime/session-time.

I've been searching for existent answers covering this scenario and couldn't find anything final. I'm not sure if I will need to provide my own Membership provider or take a different route to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the `aspnet_Profile` table is supposed to be used for this. Take a look at [this example of adding a pet to a user profile.](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx) You are of course free to add your own implementation for the custom data -- you could link it with a foreign key to the `[aspnet_Users].[UserId]` column and do whatever you like.

Comment: thats not as flexible/comfy as i would like to have. i want a code-based solution, preferably using a model.

Comment: It is simple to model: it's a key-value store. I agree it isn't the most agreeable approach however it is standard and unless it causes performance issues it seems like a safe approach as others will be familiar with the aspnet_ tables.

Comment: Why not take the flexible route then and make your own model/table tied to the `[aspnet_Users].[UserId]` as a foreign key? That should give you want you want. I don't think anyone can model this for you based on the original question (lack of details).